# Paseto V3 Node.js - Local Secret Key must be 32 bytes long symmetric key Error

Tags: php, node.js, local, symmetric-key, paseto

My secret key was generated using PHP Paseto V3 with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32) and then converted from bin to hex.
Now I need to decrypt and verify Paseto token using node.js and paseto library (https://github.com/panva/paseto).
I don't understand why my secret key returns an error that the length is invalid. It was generated using 32 bytes.

The code:

```
const paseto = require('paseto');
const { V3: { decrypt } } = paseto;

(async () => {
  {
    const payload = await decrypt("example_token", "b244ac595fbe3a6ea8c3fad93f66d15221121428fd03dcccf32203e364f504ed")
  }
})()
```

An error in node.js: *TypeError: v3.local secret key must be 32 bytes long symmetric key*

Comment: A friendly tip, NEVER EVER paste any kind of token to SO or any other public site. More than many companies lost their data because of careless pastes :)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Yeah sure! The secret pasted here is not the secret I’m using in my app. It was generated just for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Solution here and more details here: https://github.com/panva/paseto/discussions/32

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).